# What are the considerations and steps to Change Data Type from Text Area (Long) to Text Area

Tags: long-text-area, textarea

As described in the title. I need to build reports in Tableau with data from salesforce and Tableau doesn't support fields with Text Area (long). So the only solution is the convert those fields to text Area.
I have checked that in the system, those fields actually contain data less than 4096 characters which can be fit into text area.
But are there any pitfalls in doing this? what are the other considerations?

Comment: textArea only supports 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the changes to the field and changed it to "Long Text Area (4096)" so far , it works fine, and no data was lost because luckily in our org no value was longer than 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @cropredy textArea field only supports 255 characters. If any of the record data contains more than 255 characters there will be data loss for those fields. Please find the below [article](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/things-to-consider-before-changing-field-data-type-in-salesforce/) for considerations while changing the different datatypes.

Answer (score -1):

text area stores only 255 characters where textarea (long) supports more than 255 characters .if you change from textarea (long) to textarea then textarea field will store only 255 characters and the remaining characters will be lost

Comment: downvoted as I'm not quite sure why you posted the same exact answer as SaiPraveen after them.